# how these autofill forms work recently i have seen alot of these looks quiet cool?

Tags: javascript, forms, autofill

How does autofill form work ? recently i send in alot of places billing/application these form get autofilled with details from my docx file how does this work ? thank you

example
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not the website but the browser that does the autofilling
So basically if Chrome or any other browser detects the fields in the forms and if it has any information that could match the field for eg. Name, Address, etc..

It shows the option to autofill the form with known details.
You can also manually enter your details in some browsers so that they show the option to autofill whenever you can